# Faster code for cuting 'good row range' from sh2 to sh1?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2003

Does it exist any way to make this code run faster as it goes one row by one row ?

```
Sub cut_good_row_range_from_sh2_to_sh1()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For i = 2 To Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For j = 2 To Sheets("sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

      'Caution: I want to cut BB:BD, so I select BA:BD !
      If Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value = Sheets("sheet2").Range("A" & j).Value Then
        Sheets("sheet2").Range("BA" & j & ":BS" & j).Cut Sheets("sheet1").Range("BA" & i & ":BS" & i)
      End If
    Next j
  Next i
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thanks ;)

Comment: Many ways exist to speed up this type of code.  Which one to use in this case will depend on the answers to some questions: 1) How many rows (approx) are there in each sheet? 2) are values in `Sheet1!A:A` repeated, and if so which one 'wins'? 3) are values in `Sheet2!A:A` repeated? Is the data sorted, and if not can we sort it (even temporarily)? 4) do you want to move just the values, or formats too? 5) approx how many matches as a % do you expect to find?

Comment: Hi, Many thanks for your help. ;) I try to answer to your questions: **1)** 3000 rows in Sheet1 and 5000 rows in Sheets2  **2)** Sheet2 wins as Columns BB:BD are empty in Sheet1. **3)** All cells that are in `Sheet1!A:A` are inside `Sheet2!A:A`, but not all cells that are in `Sheet2!A:A` are inside `Sheets1!A:A`.  Only `Sheets2!A:A` is sorted. We can sort any sheets temporarily  **4)** just the values, I can copy paste the format later by column very fast  **5)**  3000.  Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been demonstrated on SO many times that looping over ranges is slow, and looping over variant arrays is much faster.

The 'best' method depends on the specifics of the use case.  Making as few assumptions as I can, this demo shows how effective it can be.  The assumptions made are

1. Data only is required, Format is not transfered.
2. No Formulas exist in the Destination range (If they do, they will be overwritten with their current value)

This is a simplistic example, further optimisations can be made.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim Found As Boolean
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim rSrcA As Range, rSrc As Range
    Dim vSrcA As Variant, vSrc As Variant
    Dim rDstA As Range, rDst As Range
    Dim vDstA As Variant, vDst As Variant
    Dim rClear As Range

    ' Get references to Source Data Range and Variant Array
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        Set rSrcA = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        vSrcA = rSrcA.Value
        Set rSrc = .Range("BA1:BS1").Resize(UBound(vSrcA, 1))
        vSrc = rSrc
    End With

    ' Get references to Destination Data Range and Variant Array
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set rDstA = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        vDstA = rDstA.Value
        Set rDst = .Range("BA1:BS1").Resize(UBound(vDstA, 1))
        vDst = rDst
    End With

    ' Loop Source
    For i = 1 To UBound(vSrcA, 1)
        ' Loop Destination
        For j = 1 To UBound(vDstA, 1)
            ' Compare
            If vSrcA(i, 1) = vDstA(j, 1) Then
                Found = True
                ' Update Destination Data Array, to be copied back to sheet later
                For k = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 2)
                    vDst(j, k) = vSrc(i, k)
                Next
            End If

        Next
        ' If match found, track Source range to clear later
        If Found Then
            If rClear Is Nothing Then
                Set rClear = rSrc.Rows(i)
            Else
                Set rClear = Union(rClear, rSrc.Rows(i))
            End If
            Found = False
        End If
    Next

    ' Update Destination Range
    rDst.Value = vDst
    ' Clear Source Range
    rClear.ClearContents

End Sub
```

When run on a test data set of 15 source rows and 200 destination rows, this reduced execution time from about 17s to about 10ms

Comment: Hi again, Wow ! Many thanks. I have just tested your code on my big file and for what I can say : it is working like a charm and it is very fast! ;) Many thanks. ;) By luck could you let me know where can I tell the code to also delete the rows after having cut them from Sheet2 ? Many thanks in advance ;) Many thanks again !;) This is so great ! I much appreciated your help. ;)

Comment: @Erb Glad to hear it's working for you.  Based on your answers to my questions, I think we could speed it up some more.  But if it's fast enough lets leave it at that.  To Delete source sheet rows instead of clearing them, change `rClear.ClearContents` to `rClear.EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your help. ;) Your last comment is also working great. ;) Thanks again. ;)